# spring mongodb not saving newly added field

Tags: spring, mongodb, nosql, spring-mongodb

this is my mongo db document

```
classA {
private String name;
private long elapsedTime; // newly added field
}

@Document
classB extends classA{
private String id;
private String owner;
}

classBRepository.save(classBObject);
```

but newly added elapsedTime field is not saved to database, others are saved. if I call save method second time then that field is saved.

I am not using any strict schema configuration by the way.

What do you think that can cause this problem ? is it because of some configuration, is there anything I am missing here ?

MongoDb version: 5.0.6

Spring version: 2.6.6